# I want to find the corner frequency of this second order low pass filter

Tags: filter, transfer-function, passive-filter, cutoff-frequency

[image]

As there is an isolator an between, I have tried multiplying the individual transfer functions to get the combined function and then equated it with -3dB.

Comment: What was your result? You have not asked a question.

Comment: The corner frequency would be the zeros of the transfer function. You can look up definition for this

Comment: pvk, this one is actually pretty easy because of section (II). Had section (II) not been there, then section (III) would load down section (I) and you'd be making a somewhat more difficult calculation. But you are lucky. Section (III) doesn't load down section (I). The corner frequency is ***very easy*** in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not going to solve this for you, but your approach is almost correct. Here is a step by step approach to finding the cutoff frequency of a cascaded system like this

1. Find the transfer function of each section
2. Multiply the transfer functions together
3. Find the magnitude response of the cascaded system
4. Set the magnitude response equal to -3dB and solve for \$\omega\$

From your description of the question you may have been missing step 3.

Comment: Regarding step 4 above: Don`t forget that -3dB is equivalent to an absolute value of sqrt(0.5).